# Deriving from AbstractCellEditor / Combobox in swing Table

Tags: python, swing, jython

I am trying to add a combobox as editor to a table column in jython. Since I want to have values selectabel depending on the row I am trying to implement `AbstractCellEditor` to set a custom editor, my code is approximately:

```
from javax.swing.table import TableCellEditor
from javax.swing import AbstractCellEditor

class customCombo(TableCellEditor):

    def __init__(self):
        self._box = JComboBox( editable = False );
        #button.setActionCommand(EDIT);
        #self._box.actionListener = self.actionPerformed



    def actionPerformed(self, event):
        print "well we should do something"



    def getCellEditorValue(self):
        return self._box.selectedItem



    def getTableCellEditorComponent(self, table, value, isSelected, row, col):
        #TODO: customize the dropdown
        self._box.removeAll()
        self._box.add("head") #should this be addItem
        return self._box

 class table(object):
       def __init__(self):
           ...
           self._table.columnModel.getColumn(8).cellEditor = customCombo()
```

Since I am new to swing I tried to translate the example from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor. However it only 'works' (as in runs but does not behave as desired, I never get to see the combobox), if I implement `TableCellEditor`, but according to the example:

> The AbstractCellEditor class is a good superclass to use. It implements TableCellEditor's superinterface, CellEditor, saving you the trouble of implementing the event firing code necessary for cell editors.

Thus I would like to implement the `AbstractCellEditor`, however doing so yields:

> TypeError: can't convert
>   org.python.proxies.cross.gui.ipTable$customCombo$2@3da850 to
>   javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor

As a bonous question:
How do I make the line `self._box.actionListener = self.actionPerformed` work?
I found [Event handling with Jython & Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520615/event-handling-with-jython-swing), however I am not sure how to transfer this to my case, especially since I don't want to bind the parent (table) to customCombo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiple inheritance is the key:

```
class customCombo(TableCellEditor, AbstractCellEditor):
```